# How do I get any additional focus lens?

Tags: warframe

I went to the market to see if I could get some focus lens. I discovered that there is a greater version and it requires 4 (four) regular lenses.

The Warframe's wikia says nothing about obtaining it besides quest completion.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

From this [Steam post](http://steamcommunity.com/app/230410/discussions/0/368542844485771373/) there appear to be three good ways to obtains lenses:

- Sorties
- Trade
- Buying them from the market

They mention that you can purchase even better lenses from the market as well.

The [Wiki](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Focus_Lens) also states:

> Currently, Focus Lenses can be acquired through completing Sortie missions, and can be traded between players, while Greater Lenses can be crafted with a blueprint, or bought with Platinum from the market.

This is essentially the same thing the players talked about in the Steam post with the addition of crafting them.

Comment: This post is accurate.  I will also add that most players consider crafting the greater lenses to not be worth while.  After the 1st or 2nd sortie season, DE made it so that you couldn't get most rewards twice (excepting a few, like fusion cores--now Endo).  Since each season of sortie rewards can last a month or 2, it could take you most of a year to gather enough to make 1.  If you want a greater lens, sell mods or prime parts in trade chat, and purchase the greater lens for 40 platinum.

Answer (score 1):

With the current warframe build, focus lenses can be obtained from:

- Trade with other players (including regular lenses, greater lenses, and eidolon lenses)
- Market purchase (Greater lenses or Greater lens blueprints only)
- Ostron Bounties (regular lenses only)

For the lenses obtained through Ostron bounties, the type of lenses are random and changes when normal bounty rotation happens.

http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Focus_Lens

The wiki fully details where/how you can obtain lenses and blueprints, and offers a helpful guide for acquiring focus as well.

Answer (score 1):

> [Regular] lenses can be acquired as rewards from Bounties (level 20-40 and 30-50) offered by Konzu in Cetus on the Plains of Eidolon. Alternatively, they can also be traded between players.

[Source](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Focus_Lens#Regular_Lenses)